# Assign a value to a nested property in a backbone model but not using .set method

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

For example, my defaults is

```
defaults: { name: '',
  properties: {
    weight: 0
  }
}
```

I like to assign to the weight property under properties but without using .set. I'd like to do it during instantiation.

Is this correct?

```
this.model = new MyModel({name: 'Kenny Rogers', properties.weight: 195 })
```

Comment: A popular library that will let you do this kind of thing is backbone-nested: https://github.com/afeld/backbone-nested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

unfortunately it won't work, you have to pass properties as an object. For instance:

`this.model = new MyModel({name: 'Kenny Rogers', properties: { weight: 195 })`

Answer (score 0):

I used your solution plus the parse was required but I had to include {parse:true} since I was instantiating it.

```
parse(resp) {
  _.extend(resp.properties, this.defaults.properties);
  return resp
}
```

Comment: you can just return `resp.properties` backbone will extend it with defaults internally.

Comment: There are other models that gets passed in to resp so I need to return the whole resp. I just shortened the code to make it more cleaner.